# CSS Responsive How to arrange pics with title below so that it will auto adjust the size on all phones and iPad

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am designing a page to be loaded on phones and iPad. I am trying to figure out how to arrange the pic as follow. 3 columns and 2 rows in `container-fluid`. The pic and words must resize when switching between phones and iPad. I am only displaying in portrait mode. My current code, I only specify a static height and width for all the pics but how to do it dynamically? I am also using `<table>` to arrange the pic and wordings, is there a better way by using div. Please help, thanks you very much.

The ideal arrangement:

[image: Ideal]

My results:

[image: IphoneX]

[image: Ipad]

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hansheung/87qughpe/1/)

```
     <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <style>

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    div#form-box {
        margin-top: -95px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    div#input-group {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 15px auto 5px;  /* top, left and right, bottom */
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    input#searchClasses, label[for="searchClasses"] {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    input#searchClasses {
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
    }

    label[for="searchClasses"] {
        width: 40px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    button#btn-checkin {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #EC008c;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .drop-shadow {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgb(211, 211, 211, 0.8);
        border-radius:0px;
    }
    .container-fluid{
        width:auto
    }

    .container-fluid.drop-shadow {
        margin-top:2%;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:5%
    }

    #content{
        width:100%;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .form-group {
      width:100%;
      margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .btn-plan {
        display: inline-block;
        height:48px;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #B9E5FB;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        width:95%
    }

    .btn-popular {
        display: inline-block;
        height:48px;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        white-space: normal;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #B9E5FB;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        width:95%
    }

    .textUnderPic{
        margin-top:2px;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:8px;
    }

   </style>

  </head>

  <body id="sfitness" >

   <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kJvJ5e/1847p.png" />

  <div id="form-box">
  <form>
    <div id="input-group">
        <label for="searchClasses" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></label><!--
      --><a href="updateProfile.asp"><input type="text" placeholder="Search Classes" id="searchClasses" readonly></a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button id="btn-checkin">Check-in</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <table style="width:100%;margin-left:4%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jWX2Jz/location.png" alt="location" border="0" class="float-left" style="width:17px;height:20px"/>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left:9px;padding-top:9px;width:auto;text-align:left">
                    <p>Current Location <b>Sri Petaling</b></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid drop-shadow">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" style="width:104px;height:64px;padding:10px 10px 5px">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="media-left" style="padding-top:12px;color:#B9E5fB" >PERSONAL TRAINING</h5>
            <p class="pull-left" style="padding-top:3px">Strike Academy Fitness</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid drop-shadow" style="overflow:auto;padding:0px;margin-top:20px">
        <table style="width:93%;margin:3%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <p style ="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px; width:100%;text-align:left">Plan your time</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:33.33%">
                    <button class="btn-plan" >All</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:33.33%">
                    <button class="btn-plan" >Morning</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:33.33%">
                    <button class="btn-plan">Afternoon</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-plan">Evening</button>  
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-plan">Tomorrow</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn-plan">This Week</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid drop-shadow" style="overflow:auto;padding:0px;margin-top:20px">
        <table style="width:93%;margin:3%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <p style ="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px; width:100%;text-align:left">Nearby Class starts in next 60 mins</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td style="width:33%;align-self:center">
                    <div style="width:50%">
                        <img class="media-object" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="33%">
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" style="width:104px;height:64px;padding:10px 10px 0px 5px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </td>
                <td width="33%">
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" style="width:104px;height:64px;padding:10px 10px 0px 5px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="textUnderPic"><a href="#"><font color="#00B3F0">Gym</font></a>Sungai Besi</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="textUnderPic"><a href="#"><font color="#00B3F0">Muay Thai</font></a>Sri Pinang</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="textUnderPic"><a href="#"><font color="#00B3F0">Yoga</font></a>Serdang</p>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" style="width:104px;height:64px;padding:10px 10px 0px 5px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" style="width:104px;height:64px;padding:10px 10px 0px 5px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" style="width:104px;height:64px;padding:10px 10px 0px 5px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="textUnderPic" ><a href="#" ><font color="#00B3F0">Gym</font></a>Sungai Besi</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="textUnderPic" ><a href="#" ><font color="#00B3F0">Muay Thai</font></a>Sri Pinang</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="textUnderPic" ><a href="#" ><font color="#00B3F0">Yoga</font></a>Serdang</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle for you. "https://jsfiddle.net/87qughpe/10/"
Some Notes:

- Don't know which bootstrap you were using, I have used Bootstrap-4
- Don't use table to write that structure, but rather use Boostrap Grid
- Let the image expand as per width of container.

```css
.worked-div p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid drop-shadow worked-div" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img-fluid" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <p>
        Generic placeholder image
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img-fluid" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <p>
        Generic placeholder image
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img-fluid" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <p>
        Generic placeholder image
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        <p>
          Generic placeholder image
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        <p>
          Generic placeholder image
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" align="center" src="https://preview.ibb.co/nnzPyz/7557.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        <p>
          Generic placeholder image
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
```